# Error while deleting a JournalEntry?

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am getting below error while deleting JournalEntry,

```
<ErrorDesc>cannot DELETE synchronized TXN_HDR record. Use REVERT object API</ErrorDesc> <DBErrorCode>20924</DBErrorCode>
```

Can anybody help me out for the reason.

Thanks,
Reshma D.

Comment: Just a guess here, but the bookkeeping software is probably telling you that you can't delete the record and you have to do a revert operation. What this commonly does is generate a new entry to note that the previous one was incorrect. It's common protection in such software to prevent you from messing with entries, something your country's tax agency probably doesn't like :)

Answer (score 0):

Journal entry delete is not supported in v2. You can revert the last change to an journal entry via the API but cannot delete it. You can only delete it from QuickBooks.